# How to spin-up Spark EC2 cluster with Hadoop 2.6

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get Spark EC2 cluster running on Spark 1.6.1 with Hadoop 2.6

-Here what I have tried:

```
./spark-ec2 -i ~/.ssh/***.pem \
--instance-profile-name *** \
-k *** \
--region=us-east-1 \
--instance-type=m3.xlarge \
-s 2 \
--copy-aws-credentials \
launch test-cluster
```

However, this installed Hadoop 1.0. So I added the following option to the above command:

```
--hadoop-major-version=2 \
```

However, I soon realized that in order to run my application correctly, I need Hadoop 2.6. I could pass --hadoop-major-verison=yarn, but that will only install Hadoop 2.4.

Could anyone tell me an easy way to do this?

Comment: why not use EMR? Release 4.7.1 comes with these versions preinstalled

Comment: You can download and extract both the needed Hadoop and Spark binaries directly from their respective sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

See: [AWS CLI documentation for EMR create-cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html)

However, there is no combination of EMR AMI that has Spark 1.6.1 and Hadoop 2.6. The closest is `emr-4.7.1` that has Spark 1.6.1 and Hadoop 2.7.2.

See: [AWS EMR Releases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html), which shows this diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating an EMR cluster and got it working.